# The property frame of UIViewController's view doesn't work while using a single subview under UIScrollView

Tags: ios, uiview, uiscrollview

Before using UIScrollView's zoom feature, everything is fine.
The code as bellow:

```
 UIScrollView* scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc]init];
   for(int i=0; i < foodIntroCount; ++i) {
        UIImage* image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"7_1.jpg"];
        UIImageView * imgView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:image];
        imgView.frame = CGRectMake(0, height*i, width, height);
        [scrollView addSubView:imgView];
   }

   scrollView.contentSize =  CGSizeMake(width, height*(foodIntroCount+1)) ;
   scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES; 
   scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
   scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
   scrollView.bounces = NO;
   scrollView.delegate = self;


   _foodWineViewController = [[OHFoodWineViewController alloc]initWithCategoryData:_foodData];
   UIView* wineView = _foodWineViewController.view;
   wineView.frame = CGRectMake(0, height*(foodIntroCount), width, height);
   [scrollView addSubview:wineView];
```

After adding zoom feature, code looks like:

```
UIScrollView* scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc]init];
UIView* zoomView = [[UIView alloc]init];
   for(int i=0; i < foodIntroCount; ++i) {
        UIImage* image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"7_1.jpg"];
        UIImageView * imgView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:image];
        imgView.frame = CGRectMake(0, height*i, width, height);
        [zoomView addSubView:imgView];
   }

   scrollView.contentSize =  CGSizeMake(width, height*(foodIntroCount+1)) ;
   scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES; 
   scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
   scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
   scrollView.bounces = NO;
   scrollView.delegate = self;
   scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 2.0;


   _foodWineViewController = [[OHFoodWineViewController alloc]initWithCategoryData:_foodData];
   UIView* wineView = _foodWineViewController.view;
   wineView.frame = CGRectMake(0, height*(foodIntroCount), width, height);
   [zoomView addSubView:wineView];
   [scrollView addSubview:zoomView];
```

The problem is:
wineView displayed on the first page, not on the foodIntroCount+1 page.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should consider the previous **y position** and **height** both if you want to add subview one after another vertically. So your code should look like below

```
imgView.frame = CGRectMake(0, height*i+y, width, height);
```

The code isn't tested though, try this..

Comment: I've found the way to fix it.
`_zoomView.autoresizingMask =  (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight);`
But I don't know how to explain it.